# UnboundLocalError due to code skipping commands

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def kData(self, data, auth_token, apifolder, additional_parameter_key=None, additional_parameter_value=None):

    try:
        self.hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        urlApi = 'http://.../api/v1/{0}?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=0&limit=1{1}'.format(
            apifolder, additional)
        responsefirst = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
        if responsefirst.ok:
            num_of_records = int(math.ceil(responsefirst.json()['total']))
            if num_of_records == 0:
                print ("No new records to import.")
                return None
            value_limit = self.config._page_limit  # Number of records per page.
            num_of_pages = int(math.ceil(num_of_records / value_limit))
            print ("num of records to import is {0}".format(num_of_records))
            print ("num of pages to import is {0}".format(num_of_pages))
            pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
            datarALL = []
            num_of_workers = 4
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_workers) as executor:
                futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata2, page, data, apifolder, additional)) for page in pages]
                for data in as_completed(futh):
                    datarALL.extend(data.result())
            print ("Finished generateing data.")
            return datarALL
        else:
            print (responsefirst)
            return None

    except UnboundLocalError as e:
        print (str(e))

    except Exception as e:
        print ("hi")
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print (str(e))


def getdata2(self, page, data, apifolder, additional):

    def _handle_exception(e,tries,n,page,thread_name):
        print ("I was called on thread {1} page {0}".format(page,thread_name))
        if n == tries - 1:
            print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            os._exit(1)  # One thread max retried - close all threads and exit the process. Airflow will retry the script.

    tries = 10
    value_limit = 1000
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            value_offset = page * value_limit
            datarALL = []
            url = 'http://.../api/v1/{2}?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset={0}&limit={1}{3}'.format(
                value_offset, value_limit, apifolder, additional)
            print ("{3} Thread: {4} Generate page: #{0} run #{1} with URL: {2}".format(page, n, url,str(datetime.now()),thread_name))
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False, timeout=120)
            responsedata.raise_for_status()
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
                        break

        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
            print ("Thread {3} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries  ,n,page,thread_name)
            continue

        except UnboundLocalError as e:
            print ("Thread {3} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries , n,page,thread_name)
            continue

        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            print ("Thread {5} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries , n,page,thread_name)
            continue

    print ("{2} Thread: {3} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now()),thread_name))
    return datarALL
```

This code get data from API using Multi-Threading with 4 workers. each page has 10 attempts to get data. If one page fails the program exits.

This is the log of an execution attempt:

```
num of records to import is 22557
num of pages to import is 23
2018-09-13 07:53:41.473834 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #0 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=0&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:53:41.474183 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #1 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=1000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:53:41.474629 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #2 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=2000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:53:41.479195 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #3 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=3000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:54:24.673073 Thread: Thread-1 page 0 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:54:24.673649 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #4 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=4000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:54:36.180142 Thread: Thread-4 page 3 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:54:36.181524 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #5 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=5000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:54:41.246199 Thread: Thread-2 page 1 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:54:41.246881 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #6 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=6000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:09.557300 Thread: Thread-1 page 4 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:09.558132 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #7 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=7000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:18.520727 Thread: Thread-2 page 6 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:18.522372 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #8 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=8000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:20.244959 Thread: Thread-4 page 5 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:20.245718 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #9 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=9000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:44.494962 Thread: Thread-1 page 7 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:44.495745 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #10 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=10000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:52.655230 Thread: Thread-4 page 9 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:52.655949 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #11 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=11000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:55:58.248411 Thread: Thread-2 page 8 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:55:58.249044 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #12 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=12000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:56:15.855850 Thread: Thread-1 page 10 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:56:15.856432 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #13 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=13000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:56:37.810995 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #14 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=14000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:56:37.825146 Thread: Thread-4 page 11 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:56:37.826427 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #15 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=15000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:56:38.059863 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #16 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=16000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:56:46.167143 Thread: Thread-1 page 13 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:56:46.167693 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #17 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=17000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:57:15.038121 Thread: Thread-3 page 14 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:57:15.062594 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #18 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=18000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:57:35.045521 Thread: Thread-2 page 16 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:57:35.062947 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #19 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=19000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:57:35.169717 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #20 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=20000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:57:41.386007 Thread: Thread-4 page 15 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:57:41.386897 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #21 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=21000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:57:47.364842 Thread: Thread-3 page 18 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:57:47.365418 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #22 run #0 with URL: http://.../api/v1/productsextended?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset=22000&limit=1000
2018-09-13 07:58:10.259611 Thread: Thread-2 page 19 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-13 07:58:19.190708 Thread: Thread-3 page 22 finished. Length is 557
hi
Unexpected error: <class 'UnboundLocalError'>
local variable 'responsedata' referenced before assignment
done
```

My problems:

1. Note the `Thread-3` in the log. `Page #2` never reported finished nor reported problem. I don't understand how it possible that it did not print the finish message while continued to `page #14`.   Notice my code has a loop. each page tries 10 times. If after 10 times any thread is failing the whole program shuts down. There can't be `UnboundLocalError`. I don't understand why it happens.
2. Both `getdata2` and `kData` has a catch for `UnboundLocalError`. I don't understand why `kData` reports for `UnboundLocalError` exceptions for variable of `getdata2` (`responsedata`)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False, timeout=120)
```

If `requests.get` raises an exception `responsedata` is **not** assigned a value and you use it inside your exception handler here:

```
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as e:
        print ("Thread {5} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(
        page, n, 
        responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, # this may not be assigned!
        sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
```

You can't have a response object if you just caught a *request* exception.

Comment: But I do: `responsedata.raise_for_status()`  that is the whole purpose of this command isn't it? How else can I print to console the problem? I'm open to suggestions. I want to print a short message and retry to next attempt in the loop. I don't want to print the whole trace.

Comment: @Programmer120 That line is never executed because the exception is raised on the line before. The `raise_for_status` will trigger an exception if you get a `500` response (for example), but if you cannot connect to the server at all the `.get` raises immediately. You'll have to distinguish between these exceptions. The exception raises by the status are `HTTPError`s not `RequestException`s!

Comment: So to which two exceptions I should break it?